# Execute Query to produce View and count record with Column value

Tags: sql

I am editing a query that creates a View. I added a case which search for records with field equal to specific values and output an int value 
like 3 to the View column called Status.I am working off a server and don't want to save the query to the view. I ran the query and it produces
new status values like '3' in the column. I am not sure how to count the occurrence of record with status of 3 in the View query. how do I do 
that? I don't want to save the query and then run query against the View. I would like to execute the query and produce a count of record with value of Status = 3

Thanks

```
select  
  rtrim(p.PP) as Id,
  (case (p.PC) when '17' then 'B' when 'W' then 'NN' end) as Company,
  rtrim(p.PP as Number,
  'Application' as [Type],
  (case end) as [Status],
  '--' as [Source],
  case  end as Channel,
  case
    when p.PENDP_PRODDESC like '%associaterm%' then 1
    else 0
  end as IsPrivate,
  case 
    when (r.COLUMN1 = 'P' and (r.COLUMN2 = 'IC') then '3'
    else '0'
  end as Status,
  p.PR_IND as RS
from MY_TABL as p
left join U_TABL as tu on p.PC = tu.U_COMPANY and p.PP = tu.U_TUNUMBER
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: This is not a query that produces a view.  It also has a number of syntax errors and not run on any platform.  Also what platform are you using?  Finally, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) 
from (<paste your select here>) as vw_sql
where vw_sql.status = '3'
```